# why if i passed objects into a function, i need not to declare the function arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

The below is the code:

```
 function createComparisonFunction(propertyName){

         return function(object1, object2){
             var value1 = object1[propertyName];
             var value2 = object2[propertyName];

            if(value1 < value2){
                return -1;
            }else if(value1 > value2){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
         };
    }

    var data = [{name: "Zachary", age: 28}, {name: "Nicholas", age: 29}];

    data.sort(createComparisonFunction("name")); 
    alert(data[0].name);

    data.sort(createComparisonFunction("age"));
    alert(data[0].name);
```

As you can see the createCompatisonFunction is filled in with value called name and as you can see inside this function, there's object1 and object2. Can I ask what does these arguments pass in with? Do you catch me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when sorting elements in `data` the sorting algorithm will have to perform elementary comparison between two elements to determine which one is greater than the other. The `sort` method of array objects, supplies the comparison function the two objects that it wants to compare. Basically you are defining a < operator of sorts for your object.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.sort` accepts a function that is defined as such

```
function(left, right) {
    return new Number();
}
```

The sorting function is passed two elements of the array and you return a number stating in which order they should go.

If the left element needs to go before right then just return `-1` otherwise return `1` if right is supposed to come before left.

return `0` if it does not matter.

In your case `object1` and `object2` are `{name: "Zachary", age: 28}` and `{name: "Nicholas", age: 29}` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for the function `createComparisonFunction` is a function that returns a function.

In essence your code is no different than the following expanded out:

```
var data = [{name: "Zachary", age: 28}, {name: "Nicholas", age: 29}];

data.sort(function(object1, object2){
  var value1 = object1["name"];
  var value2 = object2["name"];
  if(value1 < value2){
    return -1;
  }else if(value1 > value2){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}); 

alert(data[0].name);

data.sort(function(object1, object2){
  var value1 = object1["age"];
  var value2 = object2["age"];
  if(value1 < value2){
    return -1;
  }else if(value1 > value2){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
});
alert(data[0].name);
```

And the purpose of creating the `createComparisonFunction(propertyName)` is to refactor copy and pasted code into one area allowing for easier management of code. Also note if your data object also contained a propery called "lastname" this one function could also be used to sort by LastName.  Basically the one function is far more robust than copying and pasting code.